# why the content of tomcat-users.xml is cleared?

Tags: tomcat

I use tomcat-5.5.23 on a linux server, during last month my server has restarted three times and after that the tomcat didn't start because the content of tomcat-users.xml was cleared and the file was empty.
 Does anyone know why this would happen and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It could happen because someone deleted the file (or edited it and removed everything).

Another option is that the length of the file is still the same but when you look at it with `od -x tomcat-users.xml` you get

```
0000000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
...
```

i.e. the file is all null. If you see this, then the file system is corrupt. Find what kind of file system you have (the output of `mount` help) and check it for errors.

To fix the file, restore it from a backup. If you don't have a backup, chalk up one for experience and make sure that from now on, you have a backup of every important file. After setting up the backup, you have to create a new file from memory.